# Another Def. of Cantor set

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about Cantor sets. In particular I want an elegant (especially avoiding as much construction as possible) proof of the existence of an uncountable subset of the reals with Lebesgue measure $0$.

More precisely:
We know that the middle-third construction Cantor set $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to
the set $C_{cool} = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (the set of all sequences consisting of 0 and 1).
This set here is given the product topology. 
I like this definition of a Cantor set much better then the clumsy, impossible to remember 
middle third construction.

We immediately know some properties of $C_{cool}$ and hence of $C$:
- it is uncountable and compact metric space (Polish space even).
- it is a Borel set

The only property that I can't quite get is $C$ being a Lebesgue measure $0$ set in $\mathbb{R}$. 
So my question is the following:
Starting from the definition of $C_{cool}$ can we give an (indirect) argument as short as possible that there is a subset $C$ of the real line, homeomorphic to $C_{cool}$ with measure $0$? Maybe by first embedding $C_{cool}$ in a space and calculating it's measure there.
Since we have a homeomorphism we know that such a $C$ is a Borel set and compact, uncountable.

Comment: Calling «impossibl to remember» the middle-third construction is one of the more exagerated counterfactuals I have seen in this site!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the two sets – $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ and the ternary cantor set are homeomorphic, then the argument is obvious: the homeomorphism gives you an embedding of $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ onto a set of measure $0$ in ${\bf R}$.

On the other hand, if you're trying to show that it is some inherent property of $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ that its embedding into ${\bf R}$ has measure $0$, then you're not going to succeed: for any number $m\in [0,1)$ you can find an embedding of $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ into $[0,1]$ which has measure exactly $m$ (cf. fat Cantor set).

Comment: We can in fact have a surjection from $\{ 0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $[0, 1]$ by taking associating sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s with binary expansions of numbers in $[0, 1]$.  Is there possibly a way though by modding out multiple expansions of the same number to then make this a homeomorphism?

Comment: Use decimals instead, then it is injective. I do not know if the result has zero measure.

Comment: I was trying for a homeomorphism from $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $[0, 1]$ so that the image would have measure $1$.  Using decimals won't do that unfortunately.

Comment: @grantfgates: the range of such a homeomorphic embedding can't have measure $1$, because it is closed (and not the entire interval) and any set of full measure is dense (because open sets have positive measure).